# How to find the parameterized type of the return type through inspection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am using reflection to get all the get all the methods in a class like this:

```
Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
```

After that I am iterating through the methods

```
for (Method m: allMethods){
    //I want to find out if the return is is a parameterized type or not
    m.getReturnType();
}
```

For example: if I have a method like this one:

```
public Set<Cat> getCats();
```

How can I use reflection to find out the return type contain `Cat` as the parameterized type?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried [`getGenericReturnType()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType())?

> Returns a `Type` object that represents the formal return type of the method represented by this `Method` object.
>
> If the return type is a parameterized type, the `Type` object returned must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source code.
>
> If the return type is a type variable or a parameterized type, it is created. Otherwise, it is resolved.

Then (from looking at the Javadocs), it seems that you must cast it to [`ParameterizedType`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) and call [`getActualTypeArguments()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments()) on it.

So here's some sample code:

```
    for (Method m : allMethods) {
        Type t = m.getGenericReturnType();
        if (t instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            System.out.println(t);       // "java.util.Set<yourpackage.Cat>"
            for (Type arg : ((ParameterizedType)t).getActualTypeArguments()) {
                System.out.println(arg); // "class yourpackage.Cat"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup, this approach will work.  Just need to cast getActualTypeArguments()[0] back to Class, then I can call getName on it.  Thanks.