# Generic as method return type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have looked around on StackOverflow to find the answer for the problem I am facing. I came across many good answers but still it doesn't answer my question.

[Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

[How to find the parameterized type of the return type through inspection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213735/how-to-find-the-parameterized-type-of-the-return-type-through-inspection)

[Java generics: get class of generic method's return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213972/java-generics-get-class-of-generic-methods-return-type)

http://qussay.com/2013/09/28/handling-java-generic-types-with-reflection/

http://gafter.blogspot.com/search?q=super+type+token

So here is what I want to do. 
Using Reflection, I want to get all methods and its return type (non-generic).
I have been using `Introspector.getBeanInfo` to do so. However I hit the limitation when I run into a method where return type is unknown.

```
public class Foo {

    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Bar<T> {

    T object;

    public T getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(final T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}

@Test
    public void testFooBar() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Bar<Foo> bar = new Bar<Foo>();
        bar.setObject(foo);
        Method mRead = bar.getClass().getMethod("getObject", null);

        System.out.println(Foo.class);// Foo
        System.out.println(foo.getClass());// Foo
        System.out.println(Bar.class);// Bar
        System.out.println(bar.getClass());// Bar
        System.out.println(mRead.getReturnType()); // java.lang.Object
        System.out.println(mRead.getGenericReturnType());// T
        System.out.println(mRead.getGenericReturnType());// T
        System.out.println(mRead.invoke(bar, null).getClass());// Foo
    }
```

How do I know if the method return type `T` is generic or not?
I don't have a luxury to have an object at runtime. 
I am experimenting with Google `TypeToken` or use an abstract class to get type information.
I want to associate `T` to `Foo` for the `getObject` method for `Bar<Foo>` object.

Some have argued that java doesn't preserve the generic information. In that case why first casting works and second casting doesn't.

```
Object fooObject = new Foo();
bar.setObject((Foo) fooObject); //This works
Object object = 12;
bar.setObject((Foo) object); //This throws casting error
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do understand that the compiler discards all type parameters, right?  At run time, a `Bar<Foo>` is just a `Bar`.

Comment: Yes I do know that. Is there a way to get the information I am looking for using `TypeToken` or similar approach to get actual return type of `getObject` method?

Comment: @JigarPatel. So no, you don't understand what David said.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ok. Then please help me understand how does Java preserves the type information at runtime for the generics and how can I retrieve it?

Comment: It does not. Ever. Period. You can not retrieve it.

Comment: Ok. If Java doesn't preserve the type information then why following code fails at runtime with casting error. `Object object = 12; bar.setObject((Foo) object);`

Comment: You haven't yet shown what code fails at runtime or how.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have updated my comment. I tried to add a new line before adding sample code.

Comment: @JigarPatel Please edit the question to provide exactly the code that demonstrates the issue, with an exception stack trace if one is being thrown.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: In response to your edit, there is nothing generic about the code you posted. `12` is not a `Foo`, and this is easily caught at runtime. With `bar.setObject((Foo) object)`, the cast to `Foo` happens before the call to `setObject`. You're getting confused between regular casting and e.g. casting to `T` within `Bar`, which would be "unchecked" at runtime.

Comment: `I want to associate T to Foo for the getObject method for Bar<Foo> object.` Why you are trying to do that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Using `BeanInfo`, I want to get all getter and setter method information for the given type. I want do this recursively not just for the root object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bar<Foo> bar = new Bar<Foo>();
Method mRead = bar.getClass().getMethod( "getObject", null );
TypeToken<Bar<Foo>> tt = new TypeToken<Test.Bar<Foo>>() {};
Invokable<Bar<Foo>, Object> inv = tt.method( mRead );
System.out.println( inv.getReturnType() ); // Test$Foo
```

Maybe this is what you are searching for.
TypeToken and Invokable are from Google Guava.

€: Fixed the code with respect to the comment of @PaulBellora

Comment: Note that `new TypeToken<Test.Bar<Foo>>() {}` is fine - the class token constructor is for resolving type parameters, e.g. `new TypeToken<T>( objectOfClassThatResolvesT.getClass() ) {}`.

Comment: How would this work for static methods as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/30109459/2103767