# How to get actual return type of a generic static method in Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection, static-methods

I am trying to do this

> MyBean2 bean2 = MyBean.createBeanFrom();

Note: This is nothing like [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416108/generic-as-method-return-type) because this is about the static method.

Is there a way to determine the actual class of return type at runtime ? 
My research so far indicates this is not possible. ("Erasures" & "Bridge Method" problems). However I don't give up and it would be cool to do the above stuff. Please provide 
a) solution if this is possible 
b) if not possible answer/thoughts as to why this capability does not exist
c) why it does not make sense to have this capability

```
public class MyBean2 extends MyBean {}
public class MyBean3 extends MyBean {}

public class MyBean {

    void tryingToDoThis() {
        MyBean2 bean2 = MyBean.<MyBean2>createBeanFrom();
        MyBean3 bean3 = MyBean.<MyBean3>createBeanFrom();
    }

    public static <T> T createBeanFrom() {
        Class c = null;
        MyBean newBean = null;
        try {
            Method m = MyBean.class.getMethod("createBeanFrom", new Class[] {});
            java.lang.reflect.Type t = m.getGenericReturnType();

            //c = ??;//How to determine this at runtime ?

            newBean = (MyBean) c.newInstance();
            newBean.init();//something
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (T) newBean;

    }

    void init(){}
}
```

Tried [generic return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416108/generic-as-method-return-type) and other variations with Google Guava but no luck.

```
Object o = new TypeToken<A>() {}.resolveType(
                    EntityAccessTransformer.class.getMethod("createFrom", null).getGenericReturnType());
```

also tried this

```
TypeToken tt = TypeToken.of( m.getGenericReturnType());
```

but no luck.

Comment: Check Java reflection API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: @TheGuest This has nothing to do with Wildcard

Comment: @user1723095 This question is beyond the link (toy) stuff.

Comment: I thought the point of generics is that you don't care what the type actually is

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson This is different that the link you added. This calls for static methods. So this is not a duplicate in any ways this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416108/generic-as-method-return-type

Comment: No it is not, the same approach can be used to solve your problem. TypeToken is the only way to do it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Nope - That solution did not work. Also tried some variations. Posted  what I tried.